# Norm space, linear operator exercise, help please!

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

$f \in L_2[a,b]$

$Uf(s):=\int_a^bk(s,t)f(t)dt$

$k(s,t):[a,b]^2\to R $ continuous.

show

1) $U:L_2[a,b]\to L_2[a,b]$, in other words, $Uf(s)\in L_2[a,b] \quad \forall f$

2) $U$ is linear and continuous

3) $||U||\leq ||k(s,t)||_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

Let $g_s(t) = k(s,t)$. Since $k$ is continuous, it is bounded on $[a,b]^2$, say $|k(s,t)| \le B$. We can consider $g_s $ as an element of $L_2[a,b]$.

Then $(Uf)(s) = \langle g_s, f \rangle$. Use this to find a bound on $|(Uf)(s)|^2$. This shows that $U$ is well defined and $Uf \in L_2[a,b]$.

Linearity is straightforward using the definition. The above shows that $U$ is bounded, hence continuous.

The above will also show the bound on $\|U\|$.

**Addendum**: 
As I wrote above, let $g_s(t) = k(s,t)$. Then $(Uf)(s) = \langle g_s, f \rangle$, from which we have $|(Uf)(s)|^2 \le \|g_s\|^2 \|f\|^2 = \int_a^b k(s,t)^2 dt \|f\|^2$. If we now integrate over $s$, we get $\|Uf\|^2 = \int_a^b |(Uf)(s)| ds \le \int_a^b\int_a^b k(s,t)^2 ds dt \|f\|^2$. Taking square roots gives the desired answer.

Comment: Please check if what I have said below is correct

Comment: I THINK IT IS WRONG NO? BECAUSE THAT IS FOR A FIXED S NOT FOR (S,T)

Comment: @user102800: No need for all caps. Lowercase is pretty ubiquitous nowadays. To counter your assertion, no, it is not wrong. I have added some detail above.

Comment: Sorry,  I am not English, and I wrote that in my phone, so I just turned on CAP because otherwise is difficult for me to write in English. THank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done. Please tell me if it is correct:

1) fixed a $s\in[a,b]$ we have $g_s(t)$. We had  $|k(s,t)|\leq B$ for all $(s,t)\in [a,b]^2$ so

$$\int_a^b |g_s|^2\leq\int_a^b B^2=B^2(b-a)$$
and this shows $g_s\in L_2[a,b]$.

Then we use this result from theory which says:

> $f\in l_p[a,b]$, $g\in L_q[a,b]$ and if $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ $\to$ $fg\in L_1[a,b]$ and $||fg||_1\leq||f||_p||g||_q$.

so here we have $p=q=2$ and as we said before $g_s\in L_2[a,b]$, $f\in L_2[a,b]$ by  hypothesis so applying that result we have

$$g_s f\in L_1[a,b]\quad ||g_s f||_1\leq ||g_s||_2||f||_2$$

But $$||g_s f||_1=\int_a^b|g_sf| = \int_a^b| K(s,t)f(t)|dt\geq|\int_a^b K(s,t)f(t)dt|=|Uf(s)|$$

So $|Uf(s)|\leq||g_s||_2||f||_2$, which means $||U||\leq||g_s||_2$